# how to break out of this while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

guys i am trying to break out of this while loop..

```
starterP=input("Would you rather Torchik, Mudkip, or Bulbasaur? Choose wisely.")
if starterP=='Torchik' or starterP=='torchik':
        print("You have picked Torchik!")
if starterP=='Mudkip' or starterP=='mudkip':
        print("You have picked Mudkip!")
if starterP=='Bulbasaur' or starterP=='bulbasaur':
        print("You have picked Bulbasaur!")
```

I want the program to keep asking for the input if they do not enter one of the choices. Anytime they enter the right input that matches the three choices, then break out of the loop and continue to the next codes.

Comment: there is no loop... (did you try `break`?)

Comment: The code you've posted does not contain a `while` statement...

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues with your code:

1. You do not have a loop at all.  You should use something like `while True`
2. You should use `break` to break out of a loop

Code:

```
while True:
    starterP=input("Would you rather Torchik, Mudkip, or Bulbasaur? Choose wisely.")
    if starterP=='Torchik' or starterP=='torchik':
            print("You have picked Torchik!")
            break
    if starterP=='Mudkip' or starterP=='mudkip':
            print("You have picked Mudkip!")
            break
    if starterP=='Bulbasaur' or starterP=='bulbasaur':
            print("You have picked Bulbasaur!")
            break
    print("Please pick an actual Pokemon") #let user know they didn't pick a valid option
```

Answer (score 1):

Under each of your 'if' statements just put 'break' like so:

```
while True:

    if starterP=='Torchik' or starterP=='torchik':
        print("You have picked Torchik!")
        break 

    if starterP=='Mudkip' or starterP=='mudkip':
        print("You have picked Mudkip!")
        break

    if starterP=='Bulbasaur' or starterP=='bulbasaur':
        print("You have picked Bulbasaur!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this within a

```
while True:
    ...
```

block?

You can use `break` to jump out of the loop.